# Luanch a sound on page loading

Tags: php, javascript, html, load, audio

Is there any way to luanch a sound on the page loading without causing firefox to ask for the quicktime plugin, or/and chrome, IE to display the the download windows

I want it to be done in silent mode.

Thanks.

Comment: I suppose you could use some Flash ; but, please, don't do that... sound on websites is just purely annoying for your users.

Comment: I know that, but it's just one page and I need to do it so much

Comment: if you focus on newer browsers, you can use http://www.jplayer.org/ edit: just saw it supports older browsers as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use HTML5's `<audio>` tag and back it up with flash.

[Tutorial on HTML5 Audio](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/quick-tip-the-html-5-audio-element/)

Flash:

[Tutorial on Flash Audio Embed](http://www.labnol.org/internet/design/html-embed-mp3-songs-podcasts-music-in-blogs-websites/2232/)

Music on website is extremely annoying to users.